# Handling error messages before the actual timeout set in Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

In Selenium, is there a way to handle timeout error messages / alerts on a webpage the moment they pop up without actually having to wait for the complete timeout wait period set. The application is pretty inconsistent and it takes 5 minutes for the error message to pop up at times, while it takes less than 10 seconds at other times.

I thought of using an iterative loop of smaller timeouts to keep looking for an error message for multiple times till the actual timeout value of 5 minutes is reached, but I wanted to check if there was an efficient way of doing it.

I searched around on the site, but I only came across how to handle error messages and these were mostly after the wait time was complete.

Many Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

you could always use a try catch block. Use it where you are certain that alert boxes are bound to occur.

```
try {
    //your code goes here 
} catch(UnhandledAlertException e) {
    //code to handle alert
}
```

This is based on the assumption that you are using java with selenium

Comment: I did try that, but it does not capture the alert. In the crudest of ways, I am trying to access a webpage which does not exist. After a while, I get an error popup message saying the page I was trying could not be retrieved asking if it should retry again. I tried fluent wait and sleep to make sure I wait for ample time before the alert is checked for, yet it throws an alert not found exception.